# Add parentheses around C-expression in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to select a C/C++ expression in Eclipse and put a bracket around it with a single keyboard shortcut? IDEs usually have this but I couldn't find a way in Eclipse.

For Java Code, there is a more or less good workaround described in [Parentheses over selected words in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708723/parentheses-over-selected-words-in-eclipse), but this does not work for C-Code - after bringing up the template list for the selection, the suggested templates are empty.

Comment: Shift+Alt+Z shows all templates that contain `${line_selection}`, so you can make the template `(${line_selection})${cursor}` to select something and hit Shift+Alt+Z. Unfortunately, this does not work for multi-line selections because everything in the template in the line before `${line_selection}` will be applied to each selected line.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Would it now additionally be possible to assign a shortcut key to this? I'm accustomed from other IDEs to press "SHIFT+(" and if a word is selected, the Editor puts the brackets in. Like pressing "/" on a selected line and it gets commented out! BTW. could you make this an answer so that I can mark the issue as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, exactly that is not possible. You might [report it to Eclipse CDT as a feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT&component=cdt-editor&bug_severity=enhancement).

But as workaround a template like the following can be used:

```
(${line_selection})${cursor}
```

If you hit **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>** the ***Surround With Quick Menu*** shows all templates containing `${line_selection}` and with a number key a templated can be selected.

The key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> can be changed, but unfortunately no key can be defined to select the template directly. Also unfortunately, this does not work for multi-line selections because everything in the template in the line before `${line_selection}` will be applied to each selected line.